# Verificar ENTER en un String

Tags: java

Quiero que el usuario ingrese la tecla ENTER, pero quiero que lo lea desde un String, como puedo verificar si lo que escribio es un ENTER.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String opcion = read.nextLine();
        System.out.println(opcion);
        if(opcion.charAt(0)==''){
            System.out.println("Es un ENTER");
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es esto lo que buscás?

```
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Presiona la tecla Enter");
    String readString = input.nextLine();
    while(readString!=null) {
        System.out.println(readString);
        if (readString.equals(""))
            System.out.println("Tecla Enter presionada");
        if (input.hasNextLine())
            readString = input.nextLine();
        else
            readString = null;
    }
```

Comment: Si muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué bueno que te funcionó, saludos!